# Netbeans ignoring upload relative file path

Tags: netbeans, upload

**Netbeans has stopped uploading files using the relative file structure.** No matter what I upload path settings I enter, it uploads only to the server root. How can I fix this?

The problem is just for *one* project; other projects using the same configuration are okay.

- I compared the files in `nbproject` with a working project and there are no differences.
- I changed the "upload directory" but it doesn't change where the file gets uploaded to
- I deleted the project and
  created it anew.

It seems to be simply *ignoring* the config.

On my local computer, the path is:

```
/MyNetbeans/Project
   /Source Files
      /folder1
          /folder2
              MyFile.php
   /Include Path
   /Remote Files
```

When I upload, it saves the file to

```
/folder2/MyFile.php
```

but it should save it to

```
/folder1/folder2/MyFile.php
```

Netbeans 12.0,
Windows 10

Any ideas for getting it to upload using the relative path?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: change the Sources folder in Project Properties.

From the Netbeans File menu > Project properties > under Categories select "Sources". Next to "Source folder:" click BROWSE. Navigate to the folder, higher or lower, in the local directory structure which matches the directory structure on the server > OK.

Upload the file and check the server to see where it was saved. Rinse, lather and repeat as necessary.